# What is the expectation of $x^m\exp(kx)$ for skewed normal variable distributed with parameters $\xi,\omega,\alpha$?

Tags: expected-value

Is there an analytical solution for $\operatorname{E}[x^m\exp(kx)]$ when $k,m$ are positive integers and $x$ has [skew normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) with parameters $\xi,\omega,\alpha$?

Wiki says that $\operatorname{E}[x]=\xi + \omega\delta\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ where $\delta = \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}$ and $\operatorname{E}[\exp(kx)]=2\exp\left(k\xi +\frac{k^2\omega^2}{2}\right)\Phi\left(k\omega\delta\right)$.

But how to find $\operatorname{E}[x^m\exp(kx)]$??? It involves rather complex integral over PDF. Wolfram Mathematica can't take the integral.

Comment: Hint: differentiate $\operatorname{E}[\exp(kx)]$ with respect to $k$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.